# How do I mock a class from a different module in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In Python I have 3 files in the same folder: file1.py, file2.py and test.py

file1.py contains a simple class definition

```python
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print(f"a={a} and b={b}")
```

file2.py instantiate previous class

```python
from file1 import MyClass

def instantiate_class():
    o = MyClass(1,2)
```

In test.py I'm trying to mock the file1.MyClass from instantiate_class() function

```python
from unittest.mock import patch
from file2 import instantiate_class

with patch("file1.MyClass") as mock_check:
    instantiate_class()
    print(mock_check.call_args)
```

Problem is that class MyClass from file2.py is not mocked as the print from the MyClass constructor is called.

Only solution I found to solve this is to change file2.py with:

```python
import file1 

def instantiate_class():
    o = file1.MyClass(1,2)
```

Is there a solution to obtain mocking that does not involve changing file1.py and file2.py? I only want to change the test.py file (writing unit tests for existing classes).

Answer (score 1):

I need to mock the `file2.mock` instead of `file1.mock`. Like below:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from file2 import instantiate_class

with patch("file2.MyClass") as mock_check:
    instantiate_class()
    print(mock_check.call_args)
```

### reference

[where-to-patch](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)